# How mongoDB handles memory managment?

Tags: mongodb, memory-management

quote from http://blog.engineering.kiip.me/post/20988881092/a-year-with-mongodb

> Poor Memory Management - MongoDB manages memory by memory mapping your
>   entire data set, leaving page cache management and faulting up to the
>   kernel. A more intelligent scheme would be able to do things like
>   fault in your indexes before use as well as handle faulting in of
>   cold/hot data more effectively. The result is that memory usage can’t
>   be effectively reasoned about, and performance is non-optimal.

I don't understand his point. Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: It's basically a rant.  An at least allegedly educated rant, but still a rant.  And we don't do rants.

Comment: if other Databases has their own memory management scheme, and mongoDB let OS to handle it, surely it is a big difference. It may be a rant, but there is no truth in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cHao said it is a bit of a rant and the author doesn't really understand just how massively complex and intricate the OS' own memory management programs are.

This is why MongoDB does not have its own memory management, because to do so could cause a headache of problems and other nonsense. At the end of the day the OS has a really good memory management process (even Windows does) so why not use that instead of creating one that would require years, maybe even decades to get to the same level?

> A more intelligent scheme would be able to do things like fault in your indexes before use

Not sure if MongoDB can read your mind...

I mean what if you have actually designed your system right and don't need ALL (or even those you do in their entirety) your indexes in RAM at the same time?

Doing such pre-emptive paging (not faulting) in of data sounds counter-intuitive to a good setup.

If you require data to be in RAM at certain times you can use `touch()` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/ or you can run a scirpt of your common queries that you need in RAM.

> The result is that memory usage can’t be effectively reasoned about, and performance is non-optimal.

Hmm, that person obviously never actually bothered to use the OS' own inbuilt tools to measure page faulting and memory accession of the `mongod` process in their testing.

That being said there is actually a tool in the latter version of MongoDB to help cauge memory usage: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-workingset

Comment: To be fair about the "paging" vs "faulting", the latter is actually a pretty accurate (and more explicit) word for what's going on.  One typically gets the on-disk pages swapped in by trying to read them (ie: by deliberately causing a page fault, which is not an error as long as the OS knows how to make those pages available).

Comment: @cHao You can't fault an index though you can only page in a index, normally because a index is not a single page